# Excluding operator differences

Tags: sql-server

A simple question - I haven't found an answer for it.

Does anyone know is there a performance difference (or any other) between those two operators?

'!=' vs '<>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference between the 2 operators.

From [!= (Not Equal To) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx)

> Tests whether one expression is not equal to another expression (a
>   comparison operator). If either or both operands are NULL, NULL is
>   returned. Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison
>   operator.

Als from [Comparison Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

> != (Not Equal To) Not equal to (not ISO
>   standard)

Answer (score 3):

In the context of SQL Server, no. The only difference is that `<>` is ISO standard, while `!=` is not.